# SCSS nested media queries don't work as expected

Tags: html, css, sass, media-queries, scss-mixins

So we have this scss code:

```
@use "sass:math";

@function vw($size, $view: 360) {
  $vwSize: (calc($size / $view) * 100);
  @return #{$vwSize}vw;
}

@function vw_tablet($size) {
  @return vw($size, 1024);
}
@function vw_desktop($size) {
  @return vw($size, 1440);
}

@mixin respond($breakpoint) {

    @if $breakpoint==tablet {
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      @content;
    }
  }

  @if $breakpoint==desktop {
    @media (min-width: 1024px) {
      @content;
    }
  }
}

@mixin minwidth_tablet {
  @include respond(tablet) {
    @content;
  }
}
@mixin minwidth_desktop {
  @include respond(desktop) {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin header-accent-30() {
  font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: vw(64);
  line-height: vw(72);

  @include minwidth_tablet() {
    font-size: vw_tablet(64);
    line-height: vw_tablet(72);
  }

  @include minwidth_desktop() {
    font-size: vw_desktop(64);
    line-height: vw_desktop(72);
  }
}
@mixin header-accent-20() {
  font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: vw(54);
  line-height: vw(64);

  @include minwidth_tablet() {
    font-size: vw_tablet(54);
    line-height: vw_tablet(64);
  }

  @include minwidth_desktop() {
    font-size: vw_desktop(54);
    line-height: vw_desktop(64);
  }
}
@mixin header-accent-10() {
  font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: vw(48);
  line-height: vw(54);

  @include minwidth_tablet() {
    font-size: vw_tablet(48);
    line-height: vw_tablet(54);
  }

  @include minwidth_desktop() {
    font-size: vw_desktop(48);
    line-height: vw_desktop(54);
  }
}


.heading {
  @include header-accent-10;
  color: $fg-70;

  @include minwidth_tablet {
    @include header-accent-20;
  }
  @include minwidth_desktop {
    @include header-accent-30;
  }
}
```

Here we use `vw` units because the UI should scale proportionally between breakpoints.
The problem is in `.heading` class. Instead of applying new font, the browser applies styles from font's mixin media queries. I can't find any information about this use-case. Maybe there is a better way of including font styles?

What can I do about it?